# Как подставить значение элемента массива в свойство объекта

Tags: javascript

формируется массив из полей формы которые заполнил пользователь.
Далее в зависимости от того сколько элементов в массиве столько же раз вызывается функция одним из аргументов которой должен быть массив содержащий объект. Задача в том, что мне необходимо в качестве свойства объекта представить значение массива в каждой итерации

```
var roles = ['CREATED_BY','RESPONSIBLE_ID','ACCOMPLICE','AUDITOR'];
roles.forEach(function(role) {
        BX24.callMethod('task.item.list', [
                {ID : 'desc'},
                { REAL_STATUS: [1, 2, 3, 4, 6],
                  /*вот сюда должно подставляться значение элемента массива roles*/: //здесь значение свойства,


                   },
            ],
            function(result) {
                console.info(result.data());
                console.log(result);
            }
        );
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Т.е. и ключ и значение - значение из массива?

```js
var roles = ['CREATED_BY','RESPONSIBLE_ID','ACCOMPLICE','AUDITOR'];
roles.forEach(function(role) {
    console.log([
        {ID : 'desc'},
        { 
          REAL_STATUS: [1, 2, 3, 4, 6],
          [role]: role,
        },
    ]);
});
```

Comment: Спасибо , то что нужно)